# Content not showing on the web browser with React Js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to add some content using React Js. when i refresh the page nothings shows up. only a black background is showing without the text that i added in the code ? this code is under js/app.js and i am using the tachyons library for css.

Heres' my code :

```
const Intro = () => (
<div className="m-auto-ns f4 f3-m f2-1 tc w-80-1 normal">
  <div className="mb3 mb4-ns">
    Lost in Tokyo is a directory of fun places to see, play in and explore,
    in Tokyo, Japan.{' '}
  </div>
  <div>
  From museums and galleries,
  to Robot Restaurants and kitten cafes, Tokyo is the gift that keeps on giving ,Dattebayo!{' '}
  </div>
</div>
);

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <div className="min-vh-100 ph4 flex flex-column">
      {/* our navigation component */}
      <Intro />
    </div>
    <div className="flex flex-wrap container">{/* our attractions list component */}</div>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Anything in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some error in your arrow function syntax,

> const Intro = () => {
>      ...
>   }

Comment: Hello AHmed , I have tested your code and it works if you import react-dom as `import  ReactDOM  from "react-dom";`  or  you can import like this  `import { render } from "react-dom";`  then you have to change the last line  `render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`   hope it will help you